# Inactive PDE terms in FEM without Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am solving a Poisson-like set of PDEs for `u[x,y]` and `v[x,y]` in the square region `-10<x<10` and `-10<y<10` using the FEM package, there is a pressure-like source called `s[x,y]` which is pre-specified.  For example

```
s[x_, y_] := 1 + Exp[-x^2 - y^2];
```

An explanation for the pdes: I am setting div(stress tensor) = 0.  There is no divergence-free condition on (u,v), and since I wanted to have a Laplacian-like term in the force equation with a symmetric stress tensor, I have subtracted off a div(u,v) * Identity in the stress tensor itself, so stress tensor = grad(u,v) + grad(u,v)^T -s*Id - div(u,v)*Id.

My question is: if I require only Dirichlet boundary conditions on `v`, does it matter what form the inactive PDE for `v` takes?  It appears that it does. Here is my example, I apply a single Neumann boundary condition for `u` at `y=-10` (with 3 Dirichlet b.c.s for `u`), and four Dirichlet b.c.s for `v`.  And solve the problem for `{ufun, vfun}`

```
pde1 = Inactive[Div][{{0, 0}, {1, 0}} . Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
 Inactive[
   Div][({{2, 0}, {0, 1}} . Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] +
 Inactive[Div][{-s[x, y], 0}, {x, y}] +
 Inactive[Div][{-Div[{u[x, y], v[x, y]}, {x, y}], 0}, {x, y}]

pde2=Inactive[
   Div][({{0, 1}, {0, 0}} . Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + 
 Inactive[
   Div][({{1, 0}, {0, 2}} . Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] +
 Inactive[Div][{0, -s[x, y]}, {x, y}] +
 Inactive[Div][{0, -Div[{u[x, y], v[x, y]}, {x, y}]}, {x, y}]

Ω = ImplicitRegion[True, {{x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}}];


{ufun, vfun} = NDSolveValue[{
   pde1 == NeumannValue[2, y == -10],
   pde2 == 0,
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == -10],
   DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, x == -10],
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == 10],
   DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, x == 10],
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == 10],
   DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, y == 10],
   
   DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, y == -10]
   }, {u, v}, {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

Consider the alternative `pde2` for `v`, with everything else the same, giving rise to the solution `{ufun2, vfun2}`:

```
pde2Alt = Laplacian[v[x, y], {x, y}] - D[s[x,y], y]

{ufun2, vfun2} = NDSolveValue[{
   pde1 == NeumannValue[2, y == -10],
   pde2Alt == 0,
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == -10],
   DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, x == -10],
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == 10],
   DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, x == 10],
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == 10],
   DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, y == 10],
   
   DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, y == -10]
   }, {u, v}, {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

`pde2` and `pde2Alt` are equal in their active forms i.e. `Activate[pde2] - Activate[pde2Alt] = 0`.  However, `vfun` is not equal to `vfun2`.

I understand that the different forms of the inactive pdes (`pde2` vs. `pde2Alt`) mean that Neumann boundary conditions are applied differently, and inspecting with `` NDSolve`ProcessEquations `` will show that solving with `pde2` has the source `s[x,y]` counted as part of `"LoadDerivativeCoefficients"` while solving with `pde2Alt` has `s[x,y]` counted as part of  `"LoadCoefficients"` (among other differences).  However, since I do not actually ever apply a Neumann boundary condition to `v`, why does the result differ?  The difference is small: `vfun-vfun2` ~ 10^-3.  But for `u`, we have `ufun-ufun2` ~ 10^-16.  Is this something having to do with the implementation of FEM in Mathematica?

Comment: As mentioned in document of `NeumannValue`, "not specifying a boundary condition at all is equivalent to specifying a Neumann 0 condition." However, this problem is more complicated than I thought. Since there already exists 4 Dirichlet b.c. for `v` i.e. the solution for `v` is determined, I thought setting `NeumannValue` won't have any effect on the solution, but it's not true. I don't know why.

Comment: I agree, I did see in the documentation for NeumannValue the sentence "not specifying a boundary condition at all is equivalent to specifying a Neumann 0 condition."  However, this does not make much sense, because what if the user does not want a Neumann condition?  They only want Dirichelet conditions.

Comment: If enough Dirichlet b.c.s are set, the Neumann value won't have any effect on the solution. You can try e.g. `pde2Alt == NeumannValue[11111, y == -10]` and compare it to the original. (Notice you need to adjust the linear solver as discussed in this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/278237/1871 ) But I'm not sure if the Neumann value is simply ignored or is indeed imposed but doesn't influence the solution. Let's wait for user21's clarification.

Comment: @xdu It is not clear what error is compare to exact solution? In your example mesh `vfun["ElementMesh"]` consists of 606 triangle element only. Effective discreditation step is `h = 20./Sqrt[606]`, it is about  0.812444. Therefore even `h^8` is about 0.189823. What error do you expect for your solutions `vfun` and `vfun2`?

Comment: @xzczd, The depends a bit how the DirichletCondition is applied in the default case the NeumannValue is applied but a Dirichlet at the same place will overpower the NeumannValues. That is because the DirichletCondition nodes in the system matrix will be modified. As an alternative the DirichletConditions can also be appended to the system matrix (think lagrangian multipliers) or the nodes can be removed. I am not sure if and how this effects the situation here. I'll try to make some time to look into this once more.

Comment: Note, that when you refine the mesh that the solutions approach each. I can not say exactly what causes the difference but the equations are slightly different when discretized.

Comment: I see, thank you.